# Read where mouse is entering on mouseenter event

Tags: css, reactjs, dom-events

Is it possible to read where the mouse is entering on a mouseenter event? Is there any such given data somewhere that I can grab?

I have a water tank full of bubbles, and I want the bubbles to move in the direction that they are touched with the mouse cursor (mouseenter event is on the bubbles themselves).

Thanks in advance and please let me know if this question needs any editing/updating.

Edit: Adding SS of the tank and bubbles. To the right is a console.log of the bubbles properties (top) and the event properties (mouse coordinates, bottom)

[image: tank bubbles pic]

```js
useEffect(() => {
    let bubbles = document.querySelectorAll(".bubble");

    const onMouseOverBub = (e, idx, stew) => {
      console.log(e)
      console.log(stew)
      
      gsap.to(`.bubble-${idx}`, {
        x: (stew.x - e.offsetX) + 360,
        y: (stew.y - e.offsetY) + 360,
        duration: 5
      })

      // gsap.to(`.bubble-${idx}`, {
      //   x: (stew.x + e.pageX) / 360,
      //   y: (stew.y + e.pageY) / 360,
      //   duration: 5
      // })
    }
    bubbles.forEach((el, idx) => {let stew = el.getBoundingClientRect(); el.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => onMouseOverBub(e, idx, stew))});
    
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>css animation</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2 class="hoverme">Hover me!</h2>
<span>check the console</span>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
document.querySelector(".hoverme").addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
  console.log(e)
  let data = {
    mouseX: e.clientX, //horizontal
    mouseY: e.clientY, //vertical
  }
  console.log(data)
})
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/djalms/pen/PoamdxP

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for. I attached an SS of the tank and bubbles, along with my code snippet (it moves the bubbles, but not in the direction I want it to (will need some type of formula I think)

TIA